# Stack in the WhereRaw clause in the following Code

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

How whereRaw works here? If it just plain SQL?

Comment: Please check the Laravel official documentation there is clear explanation about them.

Comment: I have red this, but can't understand properly. @uğuraydın

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you query is:

```
Select * from orders 
Where price > IF(state='TX',200,100)
```

i don't know what is your database but `IF(state='TX',200,100)` means

```
if (state == 'TX')
    return 200;
else
    return 100;
```

so if `state` field for that record is `'TX'` it will be added to query result **if** `price` field of that record greater than 200 
otherwise (`state` is not `'TX'`) the record will be added to query result **if** `price` field of that record greater than 100